# Using Parse::Lex, is there a way to return tokens only in certain states/conditions

Tags: perl, parsing, bison, parser-generator, flex-lexer

Assuming that i need to tokenize and parse only multiline comments, how will i do that using Parse::Lex. When using flex-bison, the default action for any pattern in the rules section of the lex file used to be 'skip'.

```
%%
.*    ;
%%
```

How to do this here ?

[EDIT] Well, i tried that, i'm still missing something - here is my code - and result. Where have i gone wrong ??

my simplified lex file:

```
use Parse::Lex;
use Regexp::Common;
use YParser;
my $lexer;
my @token = (
qw|esp:TA abcdefgh|,
qw(esp:REST .|\n),
);
Parse::Lex->trace;
Parse::Lex->exclusive('esp');
$lexer = Parse::Lex->new(@token);
$lexer->from(\*STDIN);
$lexer->skip(qr! [ \t]+ | $RE{balanced}{-begin=>'/*'}{-end=>'*/'} !xms);
$lexer->start('esp');

my $j = YParser->new();
$j->YYParse(yylex => \&lex);

sub lex {
    my $token = $lexer->next;
    return ('', undef) if $lexer->eoi;
    if ($token->name eq 'TA' || $token->name eq 'REST') {
        return ($token->name, {LINENO => $lexer->line, TEXT => $token->text});
    }
}
```

my simplified grammar file

```
% token TA REST

%%

Program:  Element
          | Program Element
;
Element:  TA
          | REST
;

%%
```

Input file:

```
abcdefgh
/*sdf*/
```

Result:
perl lexfile.pl < inputfile

```
Trace is ON in class Parse::Lex
Can't call method "name" on an undefined value at qnlex.pl line 26, <STDIN> line 1.
```

Comment: Do you mean that, for instance if you're parsing code that you only want to handle things that are within `/* */` and ignore the rest of the data. Sort of like a documentation parser?

Comment: yes.. I want to keep the parser grammar simple and leave it to the lexer to pass selective data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, i figured this out :) Very simple - all i have to do is make the lex get the next token when encountering tokens i want to skip. Below is code to skip passing the token 'REST' to the parser.

```
sub lex {
    my $token;
    NEXTTOKEN:
    $token = $lexer->next;
    return ('', undef) if $lexer->eoi;
    if ($token->name eq 'TA') {
        return ($token->name, {LINENO => $lexer->line, TEXT => $token->text});
    }
    elsif ($token->name eq 'REST') {
        goto NEXTTOKEN;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `skip` setting, shown here using [Regexp::Common](https://metacpan.org/module/Regexp%3a%3aCommon) to help construct a regexp matching balanced pairs of comment delimiters. I've assumed `/* */` as the comment delimiters, but they could be anything.

```
$lexer->skip(qr! [ \t]+ | $RE{balanced}{-begin=>'/*'}{-end=>'*/'} !xms);
```

The `[ \t]+` alternative is left in place since that's the default.

Comment: Hi @zostay, Thanks for the suggestion !! :) I tried that, and am still missing something. I've edited the qn to reflect my current issue - please help !!

Comment: I don't know what the problem is there. I don't see anything off hand that looks wrong.

Comment: Oh :( I feel it has to do with the way we pass arguments to the skip method.. Thanks for your suggestion, again. I'll work this out and update here in case I find out what went wrong.

Comment: That may be. I'm not totally familiar with Parse::Lex. I was thinking I'd used it in a project long ago, but I'm not sure about that. I usually use [Regexp::Grammar](https://metacpan.org/module/Regexp::Grammar) these days for such things.